# Scatter plot and line of best fit - Two sets

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am new to R. I have a data set with men's and women's race times on it. I'm getting it to plot on a scatter plot. Now I would just like to add two lines of best fit. One for my data on men. One for my data on women. Can anyone help?

```
   #Clear out old variables
   rm(list=ls())

   #Insert Data
   library(readxl)
   gender_data <- 
   read_excel("Desktop/gender_data.xlsx")
   View(gender_data)
   library(ggplot2)

   #Matrix 
   times_df <- data.frame(gender_data)
   print(gender_data)

   #data set men data
   plot(x = gender_data$ "Olympic year", y = 
   gender_data$ "Men's winning time (s)",
     xlab = "year", ylab = "times", ylim = 
   c(7,13), col = "green", pch = "*")

   #data set women data
   points(x = gender_data$ "Olympic year", y = 
   gender_data$ "Women's winning time (s)", 
   col = "blue", pch = "`")
```

Here is my data:

```
gender_data <-
structure(list(`Olympic year` = c(1900, 1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 
1920, 1924, 1928, 1932, 1936, 1940, 1944, 1948, 1952, 1956, 1960, 
1964, 1968, 1972, 1976, 1980, 1984, 1988, 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004
), `Men's winning time (s)` = c(11, 11, 10.8, 10.8, NA, 10.8, 
10.6, 10.8, 10.3, 10.3, NA, NA, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.2, 10, 9.95, 
10.14, 10.06, 10.25, 9.99, 9.92, 9.96, 9.84, 9.87, 9.85), 
`Women's winning time (s)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.2, 
11.9, 11.5, NA, NA, 11.9, 11.5, 11.5, 11, 11.4, 11.08, 11.07, 11.08, 
11.06, 10.97, 10.54, 10.82, 10.94, 10.75, 10.93)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(gender_data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(gender_data, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas does that help?

Comment: @Duck is that better?

Comment: @Duck, I'm getting the error "could not find function "%>%". do you know what this could be?

Comment: @SamLaski Oh yes, try loading the packages `dplyr` and `tidyr` first. If they are not installed, install them. Let me know how that goes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

Here is a base R solution for the plot.

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(gender_data, -`Olympic year`) -> gender_long

plot(value ~ `Olympic year`, gender_long, col = c("blue", "red"))
abline(lm(value ~ `Olympic year`,
          data = gender_long,
          subset = name == "Men's winning time (s)"),
       col = "blue")
abline(lm(value ~ `Olympic year`,
          data = gender_long,
          subset = name == "Women's winning time (s)"),
       col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I could change the x-axis / y-axis  to extend them?

Comment: @SamLaski Try arguments `xlim` and `ylim` in the call to `plot`. The axis limits must be set when the plot is started. Example: `xlim=c(1890, 2020)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `ggplot2` and `tidyverse` functions. You can reshape to long keeping the year and then use `geom_point()` for the scatter style. About best fit you can use `geom_smooth()` in order to create a line representing the best fit. Also, you could avoid `method='lm'` and leave the default option with `loess`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
gender_data %>% pivot_longer(-c(`Olympic year`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(`Olympic year`),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = 'top')+
  labs(x='Year',color='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

The default option would be:

```
#Code 2
gender_data %>% pivot_longer(-c(`Olympic year`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(`Olympic year`),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(se=F)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = 'top')+
  labs(x='Year',color='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]